# Safe to return int value to long method?

Tags: java

I know this question is simple but I could not find an answer anywhere. If I had a method like this:

```
public long getValue()
{
    int test = 1;
    return test;
}
```

Would this cause any issues. The code compiles and runs just fine. Do I need to cast `(long)` on the `int` before returning it?

Comment: You (effectively) already are. [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the short yet highly informative answer. Can you put it in answer so I accept it? @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*long* can hold bigger number than *int* (big int, as it is called in sql).
*Int* has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1, while *long* has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1, read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) !
If you know that your **test** value will not pass the limit of *int*, there will not be any problem, but I'd suggest to return *int* if you can predict it's size, or both values as *long* if you are not sure.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't have cast it. Next time compile and run this code.

Comment: OP wrote this in the question: "The code compiles and runs just fine."